# Suggestions to set language into SESSION

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've created a CRUD application multilingual and i would need of some suggestions. This works, but what do you think? Can it be secure or there may be sql injection or something?
 Keep in mind that I'm a rookie. Any help would be appreciate!

Thanks

The system in summary, works in this way.

First i select the flag language,

```
    <a href="<?php echo $home_url; ?>admin/index.php?lang=de"><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-de"></span>Deutsch</a>
    <a href="<?php echo $home_url; ?>admin/index.php?lang=it"><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-it"></span>Italiano</a>
    <a href="<?php echo $home_url; ?>admin/index.php?lang=es"><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-es"></span>Español</a>
```

and then in a switch i create the session:

```
$defaultLang = 'it';

if (!empty($_GET["lang"])) {
    switch (strtolower($_GET["lang"])) {
        case "en":

            $_SESSION['lang'] = 'en';
            break;
        case "de":

            $_SESSION['lang'] = 'de';
            break;
        default:

            $_SESSION['lang'] = $defaultLang;
            break;
    }
}

if (empty($_SESSION["lang"])) {
        $_SESSION["lang"] = $defaultLang;
}
```

When i create a product or a category or something, i store into the Mysql DB just the name 'en', 'de', 'es', etc... into a field char(2)

to store the data i use prepared PDO statement:

```
  $lang = $_SESSION['lang'];
    $stmt->bindParam(':lang', $lang); 

 try{

        // insert query
$query = "INSERT INTO product
            SET 
pd_lang=:lang";

// prepare query for execution
$stmt = $con->prepare($query);
// Execute the query
$stmt->execute()
```

and to update one of it i make a SELECT query like this:

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as total_rows FROM product WHERE pd_lang = '{$_SESSION['lang']}'";
```

Comment: You're in the wrong place. If you don't have a problem but just want someone to review your code you can use https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Note : I would store the languages in another table and use a FK

Comment: @joni...oppsss..I didn't know it

Comment: That switch is too cumbersome.